# Merging data into a KML File - California Zip Code Heat Map

Tags: xml, excel, kml, google-earth, google-earth-plugin

I work for an insurance company and am mapping return on investment data onto google maps. What I am attempting to do is color a zip code map of the state of california according to a heat map of ROI data. The higher success in the zip the hotter the color.

I have a KML file that I constructed from Census data that has shape layers for every zip code. The `<name>` being the zip code, and the `<styleURL>` will map to a color being #A - #I from hot to cold. The default style being #empty, for no data. I have an excel table with 2 columns, Zip Code, and Color Code. What program could I use to merge the data in my excel table to the Placemarks in my KML file? I tried playing with the KML file in Excel, and managed to line my data up alongside the Placemarks but realized Excel cant export that data anyway...

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you looked at FusionTables?

https://developers.google.com/fusiontables/docs/samples/heatmap?hl=en

You can import your KML file.